# Creating a draggable object in android

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to android development. I need to create a very simple app, which has a background image, and an image of a ball, which the user can drag across the screen.
I've been trying to create this for hours now, following the lunar lander example, but failed miserably. I'm just looking for a nice, short tutorial which will enable me to create this. If anyone has any suggestions, I would love to hear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this : http://www.anddev.org/basic_drag_and_drop-t3095.html ?

Note the later android versions (3.0+) support native drag and drop... look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html